# Do not show sub categories in the loop on archive-product.php

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic, loop, archives

Currently, the site I am working on uses `archive-product.php` to load the Woocommerce product loop and with it, load the `content-product.php` template part.

However, in my loop, if there are subcategories, they are being displayed in the loop instead of the products, along with with the category image and a 'Find out more' button.

How can I ignore the sub categories and just load 100% pure products for each main category in the loop?

Comment: WP doesn't do this out of the box, it requires extra code to be added, you should contact  your theme vendor for help, 3rd party theme/plugn support is offtopic here, and not in the stacks scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer lies in the Customiser. This setting used to exist in the WooCommerce settings but they moved it into the Customiser at some point.

[image]